# How to create a DbGeometry column in a table in C# using Entity Framework Core for working with PostGis

Tags: c#, migration, entity-framework-core, postgis, spatial

I'm doing a C# project where I need to make some tables to use PostGis for calculate the distances of the different objects. I created the object using EntityFramework. In order to calculate the distances, I added to the object a latitude, a longitude and a Geometry object that Postgis uses.
The Postigis geometry type would be in C# of type System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry according to this documentation:

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/DataTypeMapping.html#n3

DbGeometry is obtained by adding EntityFramework (v6.2.0 in my case) to our project.
This is the code of the table that I want to create:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using System.Drawing;

namespace netCore_Proj.Models
{
    [Table("House", Schema = "public")]
    public class House: EntityBase
    {
        public House()
        {
            this.Photos = new List<PhotosEntity>();
        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public int? ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string ExteriorColor { get; set; }
        public string InteriorColor { get; set; }
        public virtual List<PhotosEntity> Photos { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string OwnerName { get; set; }
        public string OwnerPhone { get; set; }
        public string FullDescription { get; set; }
        public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string ImagePreview { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<string> SliderImages { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<string> MainImages { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public double Lat { get; set; }
        public double Lon { get; set; }
        public DbGeometry Geom { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I do migration, I get an error saying:

> The entity type 'DbGeometry' requires a primary key to be defined.

Here is the complete error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'DbGeometry'
>   requires a primar y key to be defined.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNul
>   lPrimaryKeys(IModel model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IMode
>   l model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Vali
>   date(IModel model)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbCon
>   text context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder,
>   IModelValidator valida tor)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.<>c__DisplayClass
>   5_0.b__0(Object k)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Fu nc`2 valueFactory)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContex
>   t context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator
>   validator )    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilde
>   r.<>c.b__7_1(IServiceProvider p)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeReso
>   lver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.V
>   isitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeReso
>   lver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.V
>   isitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeReso
>   lver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite,
>   ServiceProvider p rovider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.V
>   isitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeReso
>   lver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.V
>   isitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass
>   22_0.b__0(ServiceProvider provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
>   s erviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.
>   GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.
>   GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infr
>   astructure.IInfrastructure.get_Instance()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService
>   [TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateCo
>   ntext(Func`1 factory)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateCo
>   ntext(String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigr
>   ation(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(St
>   ring name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__D
>   isplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__
>   DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execu
>   te(Action action) The entity type 'DbGeometry' requires a primary key
>   to be defined.

Could someone tell me how I could solve this problem?

## Update by the author of the post

Since **DBGeometry** and **DBGeography** objects [are not still supported](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12034) by *Entity Frameworks Core*, I saw in some forums that is possible to use the spatial objects of `System.Spatial` of *OData*.

So I replaced the **DBGeometry** object of *Entity Frameworks* by the **Geometry** object of *OData*. But I'm still receiving the same error:

> The entity type 'Geometry' requires a primary key to be defined.

Has anyone tried it out? Please, I will appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: Add a primary key to your House entity?

Comment: You added Entity Framework 6 but the exception message comes from Entity Framework Core?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 without the "Geom" element, is possible to do the migration.

Comment: Right, but does that table end up with a primary key? I don't see one defined in your model. I'm thinking this is what your issue is

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have also added to the project references to Microsoft.EntityFramewrok.Core.Desig, Microsoft.EntityFramewrok.Core.SqlServer, Microsoft.EntityFramewrok.Core.SqlServer.Design, Microsoft.EntityFramewrok.Core.Tools

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 in the PostgreSql database is represented the primary key element as: "CONSTRAINT "PK_House" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")"

Comment: But why are you mixing up Entity Framework 6 with Entity Framework Core? They are not the same library, you should not mix types between them

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I was using just Entity Framework Core, but the object that I need DbGeometry, is on Entity Framework 6. So I'm using Entity Framework 6 just to take that object.

Comment: Well, Entity Framework Core does not support such objects. You can get a workaround [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1100#issuecomment-286362657) but I would just use EF6 until it is officially supported

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's a very very bad news and I'm still looking for an acceptable solution for do that in Entity Framewors Core.